# What do the resistor values mean in this RC timer?

Tags: passive-networks, pnp

I've been taking a close look at a couple of circuits (such as [LED dice](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/led-dice.html) and [Roulette](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/roulette.html)) and I've isolated the "slow-down" part for study.

[image: Slow-down timer circuit]

(The switch is to <del>discharge</del> recharge the capacitor to restart the timer. The 10-ohm resistor helps damp the current spike in the simulator. The 5M resistor represents the load.)

I can see that the entire point is to invert the rising voltage of the RC network into a signal that stays high for a time and then drops rapidly. I'd like to be able to adjust the values of the capacitor and/or the two resistors to predictably change the delay and/or the rate of the final drop.

To wit, I'd like

- to figure out the time constant
- **[EDIT]** to determine how the top and bottom resistors each impact the output when changed individually
- to know how to adapt the RC formula to account for the transistor

**[EDIT]** This circuit is a toy. I'm not an EE; I'm an amateur trying to figure out how to explain the general principles of its operation to other amateurs. The idea is to be able to recognize, understand, and (if possible) tweak similar *existing* subcircuits we find in this and other designs in the wild. Redesigning the circuit to be better or more predictable is a good idea in general but is beside the point in this case.

Comment: The cap leakage Req  might be significant based on selection

Comment: Without detailed knowledge of the specific BJT, it's experimentally determined model parameters in particular, it's not possible. With them, it's quite doable. It's just a capacitor in series with a voltage divider that has a diode in parallel with one of them. That's math that can be done. But given how close the Thevenin source voltage is to the PN junction diode voltage, the few hundredths of a voltage variation across the PN junction do actually *matter* and cannot be ignored or discounted. So the Shockley equation enters the picture.

Comment: It's not a managed circuit, though. So different BJTs will just behave differently. A lot differently, in fact. You could calibrate all the details for one BJT and find that you can make accurate predictions for it. Perfect. Then you grab up a 2nd BJT, stuff it into the same circuit, and you'll find your calculations are no longer good. So I'm not sure your question is a well-placed one. A PUJT or a 2-BJT circuit arranged to act like one would be predictable.

Comment: Calling the emission coefficient of the BJT as \$\eta=1\$, setting \$I_{\Omega_T}=\frac{V_T}{r_{_b}+R_{_\text{TH}}}\$, where \$r_b\$ is the Ohmic base resistance (often around \$10\:\Omega\$ to \$20\:\Omega\$), \$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage (often chosen to be around \$25\:\text{mV}\$ to \$28\:\text{mV}\$), and \$R_{_\text{TH}}=3.3\:\text{M}\Omega\mid\mid 10\:\text{M}\Omega\$. (\$I_{\text{SAT}}\$ is a BJT model parameter.) Then differentiate the following and iterate to work out when the BJT comes out of saturation. (Don't forget to compute \$V_{_\text{TH}}\$ in order to determine that.)

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}\left(t\right)}&=\frac{I_{\text{SAT}}}{C}\cdot t-\frac{I_{\Omega_T}}{C}\cdot\int_{t=0} \operatorname{LambertW}\left(\frac{I_{\text{SAT}}}{I_{\Omega_T}}\cdot e^{^{\left[\frac{V_{_\text{C}\left(t\right)}}{V_T}-\frac{I_{\text{SAT}}}{I_{\Omega_T}}\right]}}\right)\:\text{d}t
\end{align*}$$I'd probably chose a a more predictable and more easily worked design.

Answer (score 0):

> The switch is to discharge the capacitor to restart the timer.

Actually, the switch is used to charge the capacitor. When released the cap "powers" the transistor by providing base current allowing current to flow into the timing cap used by the 555.

Here's a more complete Falstad simulation:

[Falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmMMDs6AcWECZksBOMdQgFhADYsQkFI6BTAWjDACgBjcPW82mD7ghUKLHiQIMSCSp4aWcuWTIieckXTi4nAE7h1IAYbwizjVZMgcALqd608CKo7FsQWaOqIJMVSAQiKXQqShYZdEhkZzwNXSxIcjAicDgQABMmADMAQwBXABtbDgB3EGdXdjNK41obADdqSkTmurFGckZUxl7oBDK3EzD2mwBzNtaRoldejgMUsyFBYWWxNGsOAGc3MADdo0YIWz18pnmKl3BlS9c4yiPJDj2kPidIWmQkio-qT28SHBiICPkQSIM3ihvrUvg8ITgUMg7ldVLMISikbcoXDyslXCZkPhRoNCWYTLUTDZyhTBEZKYNFu01vSeDDMTClOsJNYebpWNoZPAZlpyFRkOgBHAiEp6hJ9D9PuzfhQxOQok9qQj4ljtVSsbCdV0oOi7hpDXNyqTwKEUET6dSMXdlZi9RzKHhlZzxm48OglsIDRbdqtVvs9WsPStaRYOBM3Viur1jQ7XCq016SZz05QkfUGatRGs1jYFsJIz6-es4AyjEXa6I9SoapW8RVKyXjDFsZ2zLmq9XcV2DU22zHLVnOSOVY2h5OhzRk8Y9hUja36QB7cC0EadWSy+BfBCkPxYIRIGAWCpblAcTeYnfGPdpHTOcBXzHIDhAA)

I reduced the the value of the 10M resistor and increased the simulation speed.

Pressing the button will generate sharp impulses on the OUT pin of the 555. The period between the pulses gradually increases as the 1uF cap drains and provides less base current to the PNP.

Comment: Corrected the first point.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the wide tolerance errors in your circuit, consider this.

1. What are the initial conditions when switch is opened while Vc=Vcc=5V ?

   - what is Thevenin for 3M3:10M @ 5v … 1.24V @ 2.48M
   - what is Ic? 1uA
   - what is Ib? (1.24 - Veb)/ 2.48M ~<0.4uA
   - what is Vbe? Depends on device, if like a PN2222A which ~ 650mV @ Ib=1ma and Vbe extrapolates to about 350mV from Fairchild spec for Ic=1uA not shown.
2. When base current drops below the current in 3M3, Vbe is no longer “diode clamped” and drops more rapidly to cutoff.

   - so whatever that voltage threshold for Ib= I(3M3) also affects the switch turn off delay

The Vbe also has a large Negative (NTC) Temperature Coefficient which affects the time to reach a different temperature of ambient.

- the hFE also has gain on the rate of change of V or Ic vs Ib

Thus you have an initial base-emitter threshold and final that determines the sustained ON thresholds with a slew rate of 1uF * 10M =10s with a shunt resistor that allows a Ib to be greater during the ON time before cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor gets charged to 5 V. When the switch is opened, it discharges.
When the voltage across the capacitor is still 'large', the PNP is on, and its base is ~ 0.6 V lower than 5 V (so 4.4 V). The output will be high.
The capacitor will discharge via the 10 MΩ and the base of the PNP. Thus the capacitor voltage will discharge according to the equation:
VCap = 0.6 + 4.4*exp(-t/(10M*1u))
The 3.3 MΩ is unimportant at this stage. When the voltage across the cap falls low enough that the 3.3 M prevents 0.6 V from appearing at the base of the PNP (e.g. at VCap*3.3/(3.3+10) < 0.6; ==> VCap < 2.4 V), the PNP will turn off, and the capacitor will continue to discharge (with a slightly modified equation -- Vcap = 2.4*exp(-t/(13.3M*1u)).

Because there isn't much gain in this circuit, and it depends somewhat on transistor parameters, it won't be very precise. Also, the output will turn off relatively slowly (perhaps in milliseconds).